# image on tableview header is not getting correct size

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have set up an XIB in interface builder and i am trying to use this xib as my tableview header. This XIB has an imageview and above this image are some labels. Imageview is fixed on all sides. Before setting this XIB as tableview header i set the frame in viewDidLoad as :

```
self.viewTableHeader.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds), TABLE_HEADER_HEIGHT);
[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:self.viewTableHeader];
```

I want my tableheader to be of fixed height. But on running this code what i get is:[image]

The tableview header is between the two black borders.The blue background is that of imageview. So, the tableviewheader is not getting the correct height of imageView. After going through a number of tutorials i went for below method in viewDidLayoutSubviews

```
    -(void)updateTableHeaderFrame{
    UIView *headerView = self.tableView.tableHeaderView;
    [headerView setNeedsLayout];
    [headerView layoutIfNeeded];
    if (headerView) {
        CGFloat height = [headerView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
        CGRect headerFrame = headerView.frame;

        if (height!=headerFrame.size.height) {
            headerFrame.size.height = height;
            headerView.frame = headerFrame;
            self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
        }
    }
}
```

It fixed my problem.

But I have to use 3x image for all my iphones. When this done `CGFloat height = [headerView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height; gets the actual height of image, i.e, 3*193=579. As a result height of tableview header becomes 579.
Please help!

Comment: Divide the size by `[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]`?

Comment: @Larme thnx for your reply. But 579 gets divided by 2 for iphone 6 resulting in an image height of 289.5 which is again greater than the required height of 193.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not utilizing viewForHeaderInSection?

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loginHeader.png"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage] ;
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,300,100);

    return imageView;

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 100;
}
```

Comment: i am applying header to the tableview and not to the section.